# What does Bob mean by "there's no profit in last week's fish"?

Tags: dialogue, the-shape-of-water

I am not sure what Bob is talking about in *The Shape of Water* when he says:

> There's no profit in last week's fish.

What does this mean? He said this is what Lenin said.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't recall the specific scene, however...

Would you buy a 'fresh' fish right off the dock if you knew it was a week old?

No.

So trying to sell them is not profitable. Fresh fish sells, old fish doesn't.

Presumably, they were talking about 'news' or 'salient information'

In short, last week's news is already known.

*Post a link to the scene in question [or at least give a timestamp] & I'll update this to be fully relevant to the scene itself.*